# Why would this line of code cause dreamweaver (cs3) to crash?

Tags: vbscript, crash, dreamweaver, adodb

I would love a fix to this problem, but I'm asking it more out of curiosity than anything else - I've tried to debug it on various occasions but have never found the answer.

**The Problem**

DW very occasionally becomes non responsive when clicking in the code of certain ASP/VB files.

It's very rare and only happened on 5 or so files in my coding lifetime. But when it does happen it's highly frustrating.

**What I've Tried / Found So Far**

It's not the Daylight Saving Time bug, documented here: http://helpx.adobe.com/dreamweaver/kb/dreamweaver-cs3-crashes-daylight-savings.html.  Rather, it's more like the problem documented here: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/852952

The affected files always contain stored procedure commands. So I narrowed it down to a single line - the fourth one in the code below one specifying `cmd.ActiveConnection`.

If I comment that line out in a different text editor, then it opens up in DW no problem.

BUT... *no matter what I change in that line of code, it still causes a crash.*

So I might change the line from `cmd.ActiveConnection = dataConnectionString` to `foo.BarBar = Hum` and it still crashes.

However, if I comment out that line it's fine.

What's more, that same line of code is used in many other files without a problem.

What's going on!?!

**The Code**

```
Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")         
    cmd.CommandType = adcmdStoredProc
    cmd.CommandText = "spPortalCreate"
    cmd.ActiveConnection = dataConnectionString  '**THIS LINE CAUSES FILE TO CRASH**
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@newRef", adVarChar, adParamOutput, 25)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@userTitle", advarchar, adParamInput, 10, userTitle)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@userFirstName", advarchar, adParamInput, 100, userFirstName)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@userLastName", advarchar, adParamInput, 100, userLastName)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@userEmail", advarchar, adParamInput, 100, userEmail)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@canAddress1", advarchar, adParamInput, 150, canAddress1)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@canAddress2", advarchar, adParamInput, 150, canAddress2)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@canCity", advarchar, adParamInput, 150, canCity)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@canPostcode", advarchar, adParamInput, 50, canPostcode)

    cmd.Execute     
    RegisterNewCandidateAndReturnReference = cmd.Parameters("@newRef")
Set cmd = Nothing
```